# Node JS: Unzip File with ADM

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unzip, adm-zip

im trying to unzip a File with NodeJS and Express. I tried ADM-Zip.

I typed:

```
npm install adm-zip
```

and got:

```
npm WARN package.json express-namespace@0.1.1 No repository field.
```

Everything else went fine.

My Code is:

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
var zip = new AdmZip("/scenario/file/05ae5db61e83b7611570f2a313f778dd1c8-7c32.zip");
zip.extractAllTo("scenario/file/", true);
```

The zip-File is in my public Folder (Express). All I got is an console output with the text "undefined".

I'm a node newbie and have no idea what I should try.

It would be nice if someone could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var zip = new AdmZip("./scenario/file/05ae5db61e83b7611570f2a313f778dd1c8-7c32.zip");
```

Comment: After a few days I looked again on my code and got my mistake. I just had to write "./public/szenario/...". This worked for me. But you were right with the "./"

Comment: Is there a way to add the file path without passing it in the constructor ?